# How do I create a model-bound Yes/No radio button which has neither option selected on page load in ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, razor, html-helper, model-binding

I have a nullable boolean property in my view model:

```
public class ViewModel
{
    [Required(ErrorMessage="Please select yes or no")]
    public bool? Completed { get; set; }
}
```

I want the form control for this property to be a pair of radio buttons with *neither option initially selected on page load*. This is because we want the user to *consciously* click one option or the other (as opposed to a checkbox, which is easy to ignore and leave as the default).

The boolean property needs to be nullable, because otherwise the 'NO' option is already checked on page load, which as I've mentioned above isn't what we want. However, using the following code in the view:

```
<label>@Html.RadioButton("Completed", Model.Completed) YES</label>
<label>@Html.RadioButton("Completed", !Model.Completed) NO</label>
```

results in a runtime error because the model property the helpers are trying to bind to is null.

How can I achieve this initially unselected state?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try like this:

```
<label>@Html.RadioButton("Completed", "true") YES</label>
<label>@Html.RadioButton("Completed", "false") NO</label>
```

But since you already have a view model, it would be much better to use the strongly typed version of the helper:

```
<label>@Html.RadioButtonFor(x => x.Completed, "true") YES</label>
<label>@Html.RadioButtonFor(x => x.Completed, "false") NO</label>
```